# Rounding in Excel Formula using complex conditions

Tags: excel

Hi I need to round up the numbers (last 2 digits, no decimal) based on following conditions:

If from 0 to 64 should be 49

If from 65 – 89 set at 79

If from 90 – 129 set at 99

If from 130 – 164 set at 149

If from 165 – 189 set at 179

If from 190 – 229 set at 199

and so on until 989

Then:
If value is from 989 – 1099 set at 999

If value is from from 1100 – 1249 set at 1199

If value is from from 1250 – 1349 set at 1299

If value is from from 1350 – 1449 set at 1399

and so on until 5000

I would appreciate some info and help how to get a formula to work for this.

Thanks
Harmz

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You can do this with Vlookups, like this grade range example: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/vlookup.htm.

Comment: How can 2 digits be greater than 100? Also in your details sometimes you're rounding down.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a rounding problem but more a conversion problem. because there seems to be no pattern to your number groups I don't think it is therefore something you can calculate and therefore you will have to do a lookup.

If you want to do it all in one formula you could use and array inside of a vlookup like the partial example below:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,{0,49;65,79;90,99;130,149;165,179},2,TRUE)
```

Otherwise do it as a normal vlookup. All you need is a two column table table, the first column contains the lower bound of you ranges and the second column contains the value that you want it to be. The important thing is that the vlookup has the final parameter of true, this makes the vlookup find the nearest match.